# usimg for in multidimensional Array in Twig

Tags: arrays, for-loop, twig

```
array:[
{
"tipo": "1",
"ganador": "2",
"premio": "45"
},
{
"tipo": "2",
"ganador": "5",
"premio": "6545"
},
{
"tipo": "3",
"ganador": "8",
"premio": "6654895"
},
]
```

I need to access all the values ​​and keys of the array and display them in a table. I tried this

```
<tr>
{% for key in array %}
  <td>{{key}}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

and it doesn't show any value

Comment: Hi. This is in fact not a multidimensional Array but an Array consisting of three JSON-Objects. Please provide the PHP-Code creating this Array.

Answer (score 0):

First transform your json output to an array:

```
$array =  json_decode('[
        {
            "tipo": "1",
            "ganador": "2",
            "premio": "45"
        },
        {
            "tipo": "2",
            "ganador": "5",
            "premio": "6545"
        },
        {
            "tipo": "3",
            "ganador": "8",
            "premio": "6654895"
        }
     ]', true);
```

Then you can loop in twig:

```
{% for array_key in array %}
    {% for key, value in array_key %}
        {{ key }} - {{ value }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```